# Team lead uses extremely old projects to develop new ones, which messes up the project

Tags: task-management

In our IT based startup, we have many leads who use old (really really old, like 3-4 years) project folder, and modify them for new projects for clients.

I was working on a project, say Project 1. A chunk of it was completed, so I started working on Project 2 simultaneously, and because my manager told me so.

What I didn't know was that the Project 2, was actually an older version of another project, where a lot of modifications were done. So, if the older Project were called Project X (which was completed some 4 years back, with say PHP version 7), say Project X was for healthcare system, while Project 2, was for an E-commerce system. So, Project X was being modified for Project 2. I was unaware of this, so I asked my team lead, which version it was, so that I could look up for proper documentations. Apparently, the team lead too was unsure of this, however he guessed it to be PHP 7.4, and I followed that version.

It so happened that the servers where these files were hosted did not accept these old versions. The version requirement was PHP 7.4 or more. I had updated my version of PHP and even the version installed onto the servers are updated. It would run on my laptop, my colleagues' laptop, and even on a different server, where lower versions are used.

However, the project folder had PHP 7.0. The team lead was unwilling to update his version. When the server did not open anything, not even  a connection to the database, the team lead started calling me and told that my code does not work. He would do this every day, 5-6 times a day.

Now, I had to focus on Project 1 due to some client requirement changes. However, the team lead is asking me to complete Project 1 even if I were to work on weekends, so that Project 2 could be done by me, as the project does not work in the local server of the team lead's laptop as well. (That must mean that the team lead has older versions of development software installed).

Also, both the projects need to be completed within a month. Even though I asked my team lead to upgrade his software, which is free of cost, he isn't doing it. And he is asking me to do both projects.

What can I do in such a case?

Comment: *It so happened that the servers where these files were hosted, did not accept these old versions.* Are you talking about the production server? It's unclear whether (part of) the problem is that your code won't work live if you downgrade to 7.0.

Comment: It takes a single line of code to figure out what version of PHP is running on the server. Why did the team lead need to call you 5 to 6 times a day? "the team lead started calling me and told that my codes do not work. He would do this every day, 5-6 times a day." If you can't solve such a simple issue in one hour or less, I'm sorry, but you need to be let go.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I did find out the version. The problem was while I had updated version of PHP, the team lead was unwilling to update his version. Even the version installed onto the servers are updated. Due to the version mismatch, the codes wouldn't run. It would run on my laptop, my colleagues' laptop, and even on a different server, where lower versions are used. But he would blame me for this.

Comment: @Skumar, Ah ok, I'm sorry. I think I understand now. Give me a little bit of time to formulate an answer. Hopefully, the question doesn't get closed in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would email the team lead (please correct the version numbers if they don't match):

> The current ecommerce project works on the production server (because
> it runs PHP 7.4)
>
> The current ecommerce project works on my development machine (because
> I make it run on PHP 7.4).
>
> The current ecommerce project doesn't work on your development machine
> (because it runs on PHP 7.0).
>
> And Version 7.0 (your version) is a "release that is no longer supported. Users of this release should upgrade as soon as possible, as they **may be exposed to unpatched security vulnerabilities**." https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php
>
> What do you want me to do? I wish I could upgrade PHP on your machine, but I can't, I do not have access to it.

If you send him this, please let us know how he responds to it. If he still doesn't get it, I can help you draft a much more strongly worded message, but I'm hoping it doesn't come to that.

As to the rest of your question:

> Now, I had to focus on Project 1 due to some client requirement
> changes. However, the team lead is asking me to **complete Project 1
> even if I were to work on weekends**, so that Project 2 could be done by
> me...

Your team lead is a **horrible** boss and obviously, you should look for another job elsewhere, and you should refuse to work weekends, even if he fires you for refusing.

But this is a separate issue and I'm not sure if you're ranting or if you actually want our advice on this front. It's not like I'm telling you something you don't know already.

Comment: I generally reply to weekend requests with the question, “are you going to set by example and also work on the weekends?” When the answer ‘no’ comes, then i also say ‘no’. Generally I don’t have an issue asking someone to work on the weekend, or being asked to work on the weekend. But it should be rare, i always show up aswell when i‘ve had to ask someone to work extra, and i always buy then dinner or a bottle of alcohol to make up for it. The OPs Lead isn‘t horrible, but certainly doesn‘t consider the OPs personal time or the favour they‘d be doing to work extra

Comment: The team lead isnt that horrible, but since many people are working on weekends, as it is a startup, he expects me to work too. Again, he told that he too, would work on Project 2 (most team leads and even managers work on coding side, in our startup), but that the codes do not run. After a lot of research, I found the error to be version mismatch. I told him , and he understood it very well. But, he is still not upgrading it, Rather, he asks me to give extra efforts for both projects. Being in a startup, I am willing to work on some weekends, but I cannot finish my tasks even then.

Comment: @Skumar, Ok, fine. Your startup is horrible, not your team lead.